# How do I pass data between functions in this Firebase situation? Swift + Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I am very new to Swift. How would I retrieve my annotation from the addPin function and be able to use it in my addLocation action (buttonPressed). I am trying to add a pin on to a map using a force touch, type in a name and information in two separate text fields, and add these four pieces of information to my Firebase Database where they can be retrieved and plotted on another map. Similar to how the app Flush works.

class AddLocationViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTF : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTF : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var longitudeTF : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var latitudeTF : UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var addButton : UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var readySwitch: UISwitch!


@IBAction func addLocation ( _ sender : Any? ) {

      if let name = nameTF.text,
        let info = descriptionTF.text,
        let latitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.latitude) ,
        let longitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.longitude),
        name.isEmpty == false {

          let dict : [String:Any] = ["name":name, "info":info, "latitude": latitude, "longitude":longitude]

          let ref = Database.database().reference()

           let newPointRef = ref.child("annotations").childByAutoId()
           ref.child("annotations").child(newPointRef.key).setValue(dict)

           }
```

}

```
@IBAction func textChanged ( _ sender : Any? ) {
    validateUserInterface()
}


func validateUserInterface () {
    addButton.isEnabled = false
    guard let name = nameTF.text, name.isEmpty == false else { return 

    if let _ = CLLocationDegrees( latitudeTF.text ?? "" ),
        let _ = CLLocationDegrees( longitudeTF.text ?? "" )
        /*let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)*/ {
        addButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    validateUserInterface()
}

@IBOutlet weak var addCourtMapView: MKMapView!


@IBAction func addPin(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = sender.location(in: self.addCourtMapView)
    let locCoord = self.addCourtMapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.addCourtMapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

   annotation.coordinate = locCoord
   annotation.title = "New Court"
    annotation.subtitle = "The court is located here"
   self.addCourtMapView.removeAnnotations(addCourtMapView.annotations)
  self.addCourtMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a shared func and call it like this

```
func sharedStore(name:String,info:String,longitude:Double,latitude:Double) {

     if name.isEmpty == false {
       let dict : [String:Any] = ["name":name, "info":info, "latitude": latitude, "longitude":longitude]
       let ref = Database.database().reference()
       let newPointRef = ref.child("annotations").childByAutoId()
       ref.child("annotations").child(newPointRef.key).setValue(dict)

     }
}
```

//

```
@IBAction func addLocation ( _ sender : Any? ) {

  if let name = nameTF.text,
    let info = descriptionTF.text,
    let latitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.latitude) ,
    let longitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.longitude),
    name.isEmpty == false { 
       sharedStore(name:name, info:info, longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude)       
    }
}
```

//

```
@IBAction func addPin(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

   let location = sender.location(in: self.addCourtMapView)
   let locCoord = self.addCourtMapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.addCourtMapView)
   let name = "New Court"
   let info = "The court is located here"
   let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
   annotation.coordinate = locCoord
   annotation.title = name
   annotation.subtitle = info
   self.addCourtMapView.removeAnnotations(addCourtMapView.annotations)
   self.addCourtMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
   sharedStore(name:name, info:info, longitude: locCoord.longitude, latitude :locCoord.latitude)
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Still getting: use of unresolved identifier 'annotation' error in my addLocation function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addCourtMapView.annotations` to get annotations on the MapView:

```
@IBAction func addLocation ( _ sender : Any? ) {
    guard let annotation = addCourtMapView.annotations.first else {
        return
    }

    if let name = nameTF.text,
        let info = descriptionTF.text,
        let latitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.latitude) ,
        let longitude = Optional(annotation.coordinate.longitude),
        name.isEmpty == false {
...
```